# How deal with MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: 'LOGIN failed.'

Tags: c#, outlook, mailkit

I'm trying to read an email from my mailbox using the MailKit library. Unfortunately the program throws this MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: 'LOGIN failed.'
The credentials match (I tried to log in through the browser).
I'm trying to read an email from my mailbox using the MailKit library. Unfortunately the program throws this

> MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: 'LOGIN failed.'

I would be grateful for any help, I don't know what to do. I googled, tried this `client.Connect("imap.outlook.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.None);`
But nothing came up
when I changed `SecureSocketOptions` to `Auto`, the same exception was thrown

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
                {
                    client.Connect("imap.outlook.com", 993, true);

                    
                    //client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH");

                    client.Authenticate("mail@test.cz", "password", cancel.Token);

                    
                    var inbox = client.Inbox;
                    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);

                    Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Recent);

                   
                    for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
                    }

                   
                    var query = SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2013-01-12"))
                        .And(SearchQuery.SubjectContains("MailKit"))
                        .And(SearchQuery.Seen);

                    foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(query, cancel.Token))
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid, cancel.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine("[match] {0}: {1}", uid, message.Subject);
                    }

                    client.Disconnect(true, cancel.Token);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Check your email server website for connection methods.  Your code is using port 993 which may not be supported by your email server.

Comment: @jdweng The port is correct. I also tried it with another school mail and it works. For this one(which we are using in the company) not.

Comment: Sorry I meant another mail, which I am using in school

Comment: In corporate networks all email ports are port forward to the email proxy server.  If you are failing the proxy server is giving the error message.  Over the weekend I was reading a website for similar issue.  The said Outlook email servers you have to make sure you are using the correct account.  for example if you have a student Outlook email and a company Outlook email you have to make sure the correct one is being used.  If the email server is inside you company firewall port 25 (not secure) may be used since encryption is needed inside a firewall.

Comment: If you application is on a Linux machine you may have issues connecting to a Windows outlook server because you need Windows Credentials which is different from Outlook Credentials.

Comment: @jdweng I am using Windows. So to sum up. The code is probably correct, but the problem is with the company itself? Not with OAUTH?

Comment: OAUTH is something completely different from Windows credentials and Outlook Credentials.  OAUTH is done with HTTP connection which is an application level authentication.

Comment: So the problem is probably inside and I have to know right port? I am right?

Comment: Port number is going to determine the encryption (or not encrypted).  I would try port 25 to see if it works.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers including note 11 for port 993.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AuthenticationException has nothing to do with SSL and therefor is not a problem with `client.Connect(...)`. It's a problem with `client.Authenticate (username, password)`

Microsoft's public email servers no longer allow the use of usernames and passwords. They now require authentication via OAuth2.

For information about how to authenticate using OAuth2, see the MailKit docs: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md

Comment: what would be authtoken,Account.Userame? I am getting NULL
... Is it DisplayName from AppRegistration?